# get the Display name of incoming calling number

Tags: android

To get the incoming calling number we use

```
  TeleponyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER
```

but how to get the display name of incoming call when it is already saved in contact database .

Answer (score 3):

```
  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(newSender));
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, newSender, null, null );
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        newSender =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
  }
  cursor.close();
```

Where newSender is the incoming telephone number

Comment: the Uri.encode(newSender) here the newSender is wot ???

is here this ??? TeleponyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER ????

Comment: In the code it gives RED line under getContentResover().query

Comment: That's a function on a context, if you're calling this from someplace other than an Activity or Service you'll need to do context.getContentResolver()

Comment: he Uri.encode(newSender) here the newSender is wot ??? is here this ??? TeleponyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER ????

Answer (score 0):

create a method called getContactDisplayNamebyNumber in your broadcast receiver and then pass that incoming number as parameter in the method .
the method will check whether the number is saved with contact name or not in your mobile if yes it will return the contact name otherwise it will return the unknown number

check out this code

```
   public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number,Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    name = "Incoming call from";

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            contactLookup.moveToNext();
            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            // this.id =
            // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
            // String contactId =
            // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        }else{
            name = "Unknown number";
        }
    } finally {
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

get code from [Vinod Dirishala's GitHub Repository](https://github.com/VinodDirishala/AndroidApplicationDevelopment/blob/master/Caller.zip)

Happy coding :D :D